# Lenovo IdeaPad A1 Tablet - Losing WiFi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

My [Lenovo IdeaPad A1 Tablet](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/tablets/ideapad/tablet-series/a1) is losing the WIFI connection around every 30 seconds. I'm using [this router](http://www.telekom.de/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/EKI-PK-Site/de_DE/-/EUR/ViewProductDetails-Start?ProductRefID=0304021000173@EKI-PK&StageProductRefID=0304021000173_0002@EKI-PK). The SSID is hidden and MAC address filtering is enabled.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: What have you tried already? Where are you getting stuck?  As it stands, this question is currently too vague to be answered beyond guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a through site survey with a tool like Heatmap or similar.  A conflict with a  nearby device can cause this issue.  Assure you are on an unused channel.